# Single FFMpeg command to merge 2 audio with 1 video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a requirement like i have to merge 2 audio with single video. I found lots of solutions but none of them provide just the single command for the requirement.

Here is the solution for that :

-i sample_video.mp4 -i sample_audio1.mp3 -i sample_audio2.mp3 -filter_complex [1][2]amix=inputs=2[a] -map 0:v -map [a] -c:v copy Output.mp4

you can also set the audio range like 8sec - 20 sec then use the below command

-i sample_video.mp4 -i sample_audio1.mp3 -i -ss 8 -t 20 sample_audio2.mp3 -filter_complex [1][2]amix=inputs=2[a] -map 0:v -map [a] -c:v copy Output.mp4

the above sample will merge second audio from 8 sec to 20 sec only as we specify the range -ss 8 -t 20

Comment: Do you want to use text file for audio?

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: here i am giving the solution to merge 2 audio in a video. it is working fine. now i want to set the sound volume of each song. please let me know

Comment: @YadavK Why didn't you just ask how to adjust volume if that's what you wanted help with? As it currently is your post has no question and therefore will get no answers.